# Forward model from UINavigationView to UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

When the user selects a `UITableCell` from a `UITableViewController` a *show segue* is executed towards a `UINavigationController`:

```
import UIKit

class ItemNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // this is our "model" - its value is set by the "prepareForSegue" method of the parent UITableViewController
    var item: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // here I want to "forward" the "model" to the ItemViewController
        // self.someMethodToGetItemViewController.item = item
    }

}
```

When our *model* is set on the `ItemViewController` we "refresh" the labels:

```
import UIKit

class ItemViewController: UIViewController {

    var item: String!

    @IBOutlet
    weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // does not do anything because item is empty...
        nameLabel.text = item
    }

}
```

**How do I set the `item` property of `ItemViewController` from the `ItemNavigationController`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ItemViewController is ItemNavigationController's `topViewController`, then you can directly get it by calling topViewController method, otherwise, you should loop through the `viewControllers` property of ItemNavigationController and find it.

Comment: there is no method or variable called `rootViewController`. Could you provide an example with looping? Looping feels a bit wrong for such a "common" task. Is there something wrong with my overall approach?

Comment: Sorry, should be topViewController, where is the ItemViewController? is it the top most view controller on the stack?

Comment: Yes it was the `topViewController`. `(topViewController as ItemViewController).item = item`.